# Nutritionix Error: "message":"child \"query\" fails because [\"query\" is required]"

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

Hey guys does anybody have experience using the nutritionix API for natural language? I am trying to test it using python and I keep getting this error:

`{"message":"child \"query\" fails because [\"query\" is required]","id":"9cb78891-caad-4336-8498-ba51c77811eb"}`

Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
import requests
import json5
import pandas as pd


api_id = 'XXXXXXXXX'
api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
url = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients'

# dataset where we are getting text data from
data = pd.read_csv('mfp_1_proc_data.csv')


# Manual Food Bank to check if words are food.
food = {'waffle', 'apple', 'cottage', 'cheese', 'muffin', 'soup', 'coffee', 'butter', 'ham', 'syrup', 'tortilla',
        'salt', 'pepper', 'butternut', 'walnut', 'cinnamon', 'kale', 'spinach', 'banana', 'bean', 'turkey', 'jam',
        'carrot', 'cracker', 'rice', 'soy', 'tempura', 'sushi', 'orange', 'pasta', 'chicken', 'beef', 'fish', 'lamb',
        'pork', 'broccoli', 'lettuce', 'tomato', 'garlic', 'bacon', 'salad', 'vanilla', 'raspberry', 'cake', 'beer',
        'green', 'onion', 'vegetable', 'chocolate', 'sugar', 'chip', 'cookie', 'milk', 'cashew', 'vinegar', 'artichoke',
        'cheddar', 'cauliflower', 'pinto', 'egg', 'peanut', 'cocoa', 'avocado', 'pomegranate', 'clementine', 'grape'}

headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'x-app-id': api_id,
            'x-app-key': api_key,
            'x-remote-user-id': '0'
}

query = {'query': 'apple'}

print('Variables declared... ')
print('Beginning Process...')


response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=query)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend removing / not posting API id / key in public forums or repositories.

Comment: @cwavedave Thanks for that. I posted this when I was a newer programmer and didn't know about keeping creds private. I've edited this post accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the query using the `data` parameter than `params`.
The response is json. Hence to retrieve the content in a json form, use `response.json()`

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd


api_id = '2aaffc7c'
api_key = '2ca7df59e0482b12ce395f5c05b9ce2d'
url = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients'

# dataset where we are getting text data from
# data = pd.read_csv('mfp_1_proc_data.csv')


# Manual Food Bank to check if words are food.
food = {'waffle', 'apple', 'cottage', 'cheese', 'muffin', 'soup', 'coffee', 'butter', 'ham', 'syrup', 'tortilla',
        'salt', 'pepper', 'butternut', 'walnut', 'cinnamon', 'kale', 'spinach', 'banana', 'bean', 'turkey', 'jam',
        'carrot', 'cracker', 'rice', 'soy', 'tempura', 'sushi', 'orange', 'pasta', 'chicken', 'beef', 'fish', 'lamb',
        'pork', 'broccoli', 'lettuce', 'tomato', 'garlic', 'bacon', 'salad', 'vanilla', 'raspberry', 'cake', 'beer',
        'green', 'onion', 'vegetable', 'chocolate', 'sugar', 'chip', 'cookie', 'milk', 'cashew', 'vinegar', 'artichoke',
        'cheddar', 'cauliflower', 'pinto', 'egg', 'peanut', 'cocoa', 'avocado', 'pomegranate', 'clementine', 'grape'}

headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'x-app-id': api_id,
            'x-app-key': api_key,
            'x-remote-user-id': '0'
}

query = {
    "query":"apple"
}

print('Variables declared... ')
print('Beginning Process...')


response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=query)

print(response.text)
```

Output:

```
Variables declared...
Beginning Process...
{"foods":[{"food_name":"apple","brand_name":null,"serving_qty":1,"serving_unit":"medium (3\" dia)","serving_weight_grams":182,"nf_calories":94.64,"nf_total_fat":0.31,"nf_saturated_fat":0.05,"nf_cholesterol":0,"nf_sodium":1.82,"nf_total_carbohydrate":25.13,"nf_dietary_fiber":4.37,"nf_sugars":18.91,"nf_protein":0.47,"nf_potassium":194.74,"nf_p":20.02,"full_nutrients":[{"attr_id":203,"value":0.4732},{"attr_id":204,"value":0.3094},{"attr_id":205,"value":25.1342},{"attr_id":207,"value":0.3458},{"attr_id":208,"value":94.64},{"attr_id":209,"value":0.091},{"attr_id":210,"value":3.7674},{"attr_id":211,"value":4.4226},{"attr_id":212,"value":10.738},{"attr_id":213,"value":0},{"attr_id":214,"value":0},{"attr_id":221,"value":0},{"attr_id":255,"value":155.7192},{"attr_id":262,"value":0},{"attr_id":263,"value":0},{"attr_id":268,"value":396.76},{"attr_id":269,"value":18.9098},{"attr_id":287,"value":0},{"attr_id":291,"value":4.368},{"attr_id":301,"value":10.92},{"attr_id":303,"value":0.2184},{"attr_id":304,"value":9.1},{"attr_id":305,"value":20.02},{"attr_id":306,"value":194.74},{"attr_id":307,"value":1.82},{"attr_id":309,"value":0.0728},{"attr_id":312,"value":0.0491},{"attr_id":313,"value":6.006},{"attr_id":315,"value":0.0637},{"attr_id":317,"value":0},{"attr_id":318,"value":98.28},{"attr_id":319,"value":0},{"attr_id":320,"value":5.46},{"attr_id":321,"value":49.14},{"attr_id":322,"value":0},{"attr_id":323,"value":0.3276},{"attr_id":324,"value":0},{"attr_id":328,"value":0},{"attr_id":334,"value":20.02},{"attr_id":337,"value":0},{"attr_id":338,"value":52.78},{"attr_id":341,"value":0},{"attr_id":342,"value":0},{"attr_id":343,"value":0},{"attr_id":401,"value":8.372},{"attr_id":404,"value":0.0309},{"attr_id":405,"value":0.0473},{"attr_id":406,"value":0.1656},{"attr_id":410,"value":0.111},{"attr_id":415,"value":0.0746},{"attr_id":417,"value":5.46},{"attr_id":418,"value":0},{"attr_id":421,"value":6.188},{"attr_id":429,"value":0},{"attr_id":430,"value":4.004},{"attr_id":431,"value":0},{"attr_id":432,"value":5.46},{"attr_id":435,"value":5.46},{"attr_id":454,"value":0.182},{"attr_id":501,"value":0.0018},{"attr_id":502,"value":0.0109},{"attr_id":503,"value":0.0109},{"attr_id":504,"value":0.0237},{"attr_id":505,"value":0.0218},{"attr_id":506,"value":0.0018},{"attr_id":507,"value":0.0018},{"attr_id":508,"value":0.0109},{"attr_id":509,"value":0.0018},{"attr_id":510,"value":0.0218},{"attr_id":511,"value":0.0109},{"attr_id":512,"value":0.0091},{"attr_id":513,"value":0.02},{"attr_id":514,"value":0.1274},{"attr_id":515,"value":0.0455},{"attr_id":516,"value":0.0164},{"attr_id":517,"value":0.0109},{"attr_id":518,"value":0.0182},{"attr_id":601,"value":0},{"attr_id":605,"value":0},{"attr_id":606,"value":0.051},{"attr_id":607,"value":0},{"attr_id":608,"value":0},{"attr_id":609,"value":0},{"attr_id":610,"value":0},{"attr_id":611,"value":0},{"attr_id":612,"value":0.0018},{"attr_id":613,"value":0.0437},{"attr_id":614,"value":0.0055},{"attr_id":617,"value":0.0127},{"attr_id":618,"value":0.0783},{"attr_id":619,"value":0.0164},{"attr_id":620,"value":0},{"attr_id":621,"value":0},{"attr_id":626,"value":0},{"attr_id":627,"value":0},{"attr_id":628,"value":0},{"attr_id":629,"value":0},{"attr_id":630,"value":0},{"attr_id":631,"value":0},{"attr_id":636,"value":21.84},{"attr_id":645,"value":0.0127},{"attr_id":646,"value":0.0928}],"nix_brand_name":null,"nix_brand_id":null,"nix_item_name":null,"nix_item_id":null,"upc":null,"consumed_at":"2020-07-30T02:49:04+00:00","metadata":{"is_raw_food":false},"source":1,"ndb_no":9003,"tags":{"item":"apple","measure":null,"quantity":"1.0","food_group":3,"tag_id":384},"alt_measures":[{"serving_weight":242,"measure":"NLEA serving","seq":7,"qty":1},{"serving_weight":101,"measure":"extra small (2-1/2\" dia)","seq":6,"qty":1},{"serving_weight":149,"measure":"small (2-3/4\" dia)","seq":5,"qty":1},{"serving_weight":182,"measure":"medium (3\" dia)","seq":4,"qty":1},{"serving_weight":223,"measure":"large (3-1/4\" dia)","seq":3,"qty":1},{"serving_weight":109,"measure":"cup slices","seq":2,"qty":1},{"serving_weight":125,"measure":"cup, quartered or chopped","seq":1,"qty":1},{"serving_weight":28.35,"measure":"oz","seq":80,"qty":1},{"serving_weight":100,"measure":"g","seq":null,"qty":100}],"lat":null,"lng":null,"meal_type":5,"photo":{"thumb":"https://nix-tag-images.s3.amazonaws.com/384_thumb.jpg","highres":"https://nix-tag-images.s3.amazonaws.com/384_highres.jpg","is_user_uploaded":false},"sub_recipe":null}]}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much I've been trying to get this project going for a while XD

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the post request with json for parameters
Example:

```
import requests

nutritionix_url = "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients"

params_config = {
    "query": "for breakfast i ate 2 eggs, bacon, and french toast",
    "timezone": "US/Eastern",

}

HEADERS = {
    "content-Type": "application/json",
    "x-app-id": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "x-app-key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",

}

response = requests.post(url=nutritionix_url, json=params_config, headers=HEADERS)

   

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

i removed

```
"Content-Type": "json",
```

from headers,

```
HEADERS = {
"x-app-id": APP_ID,
"x-app-key": API_KEY,
```

}

and now it runs fine, hope this works for you too

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).